# apply jquery only to current element

Tags: jquery

can anyone help me with this. What I'm trying to do is show the product summary only when hovered to product thumbnail. How can I apply the jquery code below to current element only.

```
jQuery(".product-thumbnail").hover (function() {
   jQuery(".product-summary").attr("id","ps-id");
});
jQuery(".product-thumbnail").mouseout (function() {
   jQuery(".product-summary").removeAttr("id");
});
```

I tried adding "this" but it doesnt work.

```
jQuery(".product-thumbnail", this).hover (function() {
    jQuery(".product-summary").attr("id","ps-id");
});
    jQuery(".product-thumbnail", this).mouseout (function() {
jQuery(".product-summary").removeAttr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the jquery´s .hover [has two arguments](https://api.jquery.com/hover/),  handlerIn and handlerOut, so you dont need to use mouseleave

inside the hover handler you can refer to the current hovered item with `this` and by using `jQuery(this)`  it makes all jquery methods available to that element

I´m now assuming that .product-summary is a children of .product-thumbnail so that .find( would find it, maybe using .closest or sth. similiar makes more sense for your markup

```
jQuery(".product-thumbnail").hover(function() {

   jQuery(this).find(".product-summary").attr("id","ps-id");

}, function() {

   jQuery(this).find(".product-summary").removeAttr("id");

});
```